# Search the Modelica.Userguide

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am learning Modelica language, the modelica.Reference is very useful, but I didn't find a website that allows me to search for a specific word in this document. I have to try to use a custom search with Google. But it didn't work fine.

Did anyone know a website or some method that allows me to do this.

[image]

Comment: Using `site:build.openmodelica.org` should work just fine in Google searches, see e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=site:build.openmodelica.org+stream

Comment: As an alternative, try `site:doc.modelica.org` like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:doc.modelica.org+stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the tags and other questions I assume that you have Dymola. In Dymola you can right-click "Modelica.User's Guide" and select "Search". If you activate the check-box "Modelica text", Dymola will search the full Modelica text, including the documentation.

[image: Dymola Search-UI]

For other Models the "Full documentation" check-blox would probably make more sense.